# Is there a scraper application like KimonoLabs?

Tags: web-scraping

I have used scrapy and beautiful soup many times, however find kimonolabs solution much easier and faster. The only problem is that sometimes jobs do need a bit of tweaking, which is not possible (e.g., crawling using a unique pattern).

Is there any other solution which combines the ease with optional complexity?  Mainly I want to define a page scraping template using a WYSIWYG interface, and then programatically write the crawler.

Answer (score 3):

Use an [Import.io](http://www.import.io) extractor.

1. [Download](https://import.io/advanced-data-platform) the Import.io browser
2. [Create an extractor](http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/247564-create-an-extractor) (what you call a "scraping template")
3. From your code [use the extractor's REST API](http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/465458)

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I'm one of the founders of ParseHub.

ParseHub tries to solve exactly this problem. It gives you a gui and powerful tools for defining templates visually, and falls back to a subset of javascript if you need more fine-grained control. All of the programming primitives that you're familiar with (if, for, break, recursion, etc.) are available.

You can find it at www.parsehub.com

Answer (score 1):

Try [Agenty](https://www.agenty.com)

Agenty has exact same feature to scrape websites, and the Chrome extension to setup the scraping agents. You can just install the extension and create agents to scrape any site.

[image]

FYI : We also <s>have plan to launch hosted solution and REST API by April, 2016</s> (Update - [API is available now](https://www.agenty.com/docs/api/))

You may see more details on website <s>(www.datascraping.co)</s> now [Agenty.com](https://www.agenty.com)

Disclosure : I'm one of the founding member

Comment: Looks great and I would be happy to give it a try, but I am on osx :(

Comment: Will be launching the REST API and web portal soon will work on any OS, signup on website and all users will get an email as launched :)